# Error: use of deleted function ‘test::test (const test&) C++ in combination with a vector

Tags: c++, c++11

I have an issue I don't understand. I have a class that spawns a thread. All OK. I make a new object - All OK. If I store these in a vector to iterate through my code fails to compile. I use g++ 4.9 i686. I made the following short program that exactly mimics the problem as the real code is fairly extensive.
If someone could clarify or hand me a solution that would be great for my pet project as I'm stuck with this. Code below:

```
#include <thread>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class test
{
public:
    test();
    void setstring(std::string s);
    ~test() { }
    void runThread() { m_thread = std::thread(&test::print, this); }
    void stop() {on=false;m_thread.join(); }
private:
    std::string s;
    bool on=false;
    std::string m_data;
    std::thread m_thread;
    void print();
};

test::test(){s="";m_data="";}

void test:: print() { std::cout << "I'm running" << '\n'; on = true;
    while(on==true){std::cout << m_data << '\n';}
}

void test:: setstring(std::string s){m_data = s;}

int main()
{
//this works
test one ;
one.setstring("thread running");
one.runThread();
getchar();
one.stop();
std::cout << "I've stopped" << '\n';

std::vector<test> testvec;
test *tst;
tst= new test;
//testvec.push_back(*tst);   //FAILES TO COMPILE
delete tst;
}
```

Comment: You have a backtick right after `<vector>`, not sure if that is a problem

Comment: Constructor and destructor should be removed, do nothing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The version of [`std::vector::push_back`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/push_back) you are using requires a copyable object and your class is not copyable.  The reason for that is that [`std::thread`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/thread) is non copyable

> `thread(const thread&) = delete;`

Since it is non copyable the default copy constructor for your class gets deleted.

To add a default `test` to `testvec` you can use [`std::vector::emplace_back`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/emplace_back)

```
testvec.emplace_back();
```

or by constructing a temporary in in the call to `push_back`

```
testvec.push_back(test());
```

Which will call the r-value reference overload of `push_back()`

You also need to get rid of the constructor and destructor as they prevent the auto creation of the move constructor that you class needs to work correctly.  A rule of thumb is that if your class only contains POD types or POD like types(objects that take care of themselves) then you do not need to create any constructors as the ones provided by the compiler will work.

Comment: I understand the reason now - I'm however unable to solve it  I keep getting use of deleted function ‘std::thread::thread(const std::thread&) can you try to compile it?

Comment: Because there is a user-provided destructor, there are no implicitly-generated move constructor for `test`.  @ZoOl007 will either have to write the move-constructor and move-assignment operator, or (preferably) remove the destructor.

Comment: `vector::emplace_back` still requires MoveAssignable because it may cause a reallocation

Comment: @M.M I have added to my answer.  That should take care of it.

Comment: He can keep the constructor, it's just the destructor that suppresses the move operations.

Comment: A combination of both answers worked for me. emplace_back kept giving problems but I got rid off the constructor and destructor, included <utility> and used `testvec.push_back(std::move(*tst));` I can now iterate through the vector and launch threads from within. Thank you all very much!

Answer (score 2):

As others have said, `push_back` requires the object to be copyable, however you can use `std::move` to move the thread into the vector, avoiding the copy.

```
testvec.push_back(std::move(*tst));
```

Comment: doesn't work either - I'm missing something - can you try to compile it? it needs pthread for the linker and the -std=c++11 -pthread flags